# Login with Twitter is not working from last 2 weeks

Tags: asp.net, twitter

In my Web application I have integrated login with twitter option.
Users can login with twitter in my web application. This feature worked correctly, but last 2 weeks it gives me error :
Getting (401) Unauthorized https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token

If I already login with twitter in other tab and When I try to login with twitter in application, It works correctly, But I not already login with twitter, and try to login with my application, then it gives me unauthorized error(401).

helppppppp..

Answer (score 0):

In the last month, there has been a [change to the Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/24239).  You can now **only** call it using HTTPS.

You should ensure that **all** the URLs you / your library are using starts with

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/
```

(Notice the extra `s` after the `http`.)